# Is there a way to remove a specific formula from multiple formulated cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a lot of cells that has round formula. Is there a way to remove all round(#,#) formula without retaining the original formula? Unfortunately, each cells has its ***unique*** formula, thus I ***can't*** remove round formula on one cell and apply it to the rest. I am open to all suggestions as long as the round formula is removed and retain the main formula.

*sample of data...*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your formula look all like `=Round(###,###)` you can strip off the first 7 characters and use `InStrRev` to find the last comme from the end to strip that off too.

The following will do that for the selected cells.

```
Public Sub StripOffRound()
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Selection
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In AffectedRange.Cells
        If Cell.HasFormula Then
            Dim CellFormula As String
            CellFormula = Cell.Formula
            
            If Left$(CellFormula, 7) = "=ROUND(" Then
                CellFormula = Mid$(CellFormula, 8)
                CellFormula = Left$(CellFormula, InStrRev(CellFormula, ",") - 1)
                
                Cell.Formula = "=" & CellFormula
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute - my solution looks very similar. Small optimization: Use `AffectedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`, then you don't need to check every cell for `HasFormula`

Comment: @FunThomas True ;) I put that check just in case as I assumed that the OP will only select the cells with those formulas anyway. But yes, if it is planned to run that on the entire worksheet `AffectedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)` would be the better solution.

Comment: Awesome this one works! but I do have a question, if the Round(###,###) formula is inside the iferror, what should be the case? [ =Iferror(Round(###,###),0) ], I just found out that not all are plain Round(###,###).